# How can I print the given pattern with just a loop and an inner loop? Instead of using 4 loops

Tags: java, loops, indexoutofboundsexception, chess

**This is the code snippet, which should mark the Field of a Bishop (chess figure)**
**Sadly and obviously I am getting an array out of bounds exceptions - can someone solve the issue please?**

```
int i = 1, j = 1;

 while (i <= 8) {
      board.markField(9-i, i);

      i++;

      while (j <= 8) {

          board.markField(j, i); // here is the error
          j++;      // j =2
          break;
      }
  }
```

**Desired Output**

```
o o o o o o o x
x o o o o o x o
o x o o o x o o
o o x o x o o o
o o o x o o o o
o o x o x o o o
o x o o o x o o
x o o o o o x o
```

*It is not necessary, to help me with printing out the **x** or the **o**, I have a working function, that does this very good*

```java
 public void markField(int x, int y){

     board[x-1][y-1] = true;
 }
```

Comment: In which line you are getting this exception ? Please provide some more code so that we can understand you game logic a bit more.

Comment: It should be more understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `for-loops` are enough to get it done, however, you will have to have some extra variables to get it done. Code:

```
int start = 0, end = 7;
boolean flag = false;
for(int i= 0; i<8; i++)
{
    if(i > 0)
        flag = true;
    for(int j= 0; j<8; j++)
    {
        if(flag && j==start)
        {
            //System.out.printf("x ");
            board.markField(i,j);
            start++;
            if(start == end+1)
                end--;
            flag = false;
            continue;
        }

        if(j==end)
        {
            //System.out.printf("x ");
            board.markField(i,j);
            end--;
            continue;
        }
        //System.out.printf("o ");
        board.markField(i,j);
    }
    //System.out.println();
}
```

As we are calling `markField()` with correct array indices, so,  change your `markField()` like this:

```
public void markField(int x, int y){

 board[x][y] = true;
}
```

Comment: your code marks all fields as true, but then I get only 'x' and no 'o' visible on the screen.

Comment: All fields means ? all correct fields or whole board array ? "I get only 'x' and no 'o' visible on the screen" yes thats what should be visible on the screen as pointed out on your question

Comment: I posted the output, what I wanted to achieve with the code...

Comment: Yes well my code is giving the same output as posted by you, you can un-comment the `Syste,.out.println()` lines and see it yourself. Sorry but it is not clear what issue you are having with my code

Comment: o x o o o o o x
 
o o x o o o x o 
o o o x o x o o 
o o o o x o o o 
o o o x o x o o 
o o x o o o x o 
o x o o o o o x 
x o o o o o o o

Comment: o o o o o o o x
x o o o o o x o
o x o o o x o o
o o x o x o o o
o o o x o o o o
o o x o x o o o
o x o o o x o o
x o o o o o x o

Comment: @TorbenIT un-comment the last `System.out.println()` it prints new line, i think you are running code without uncommenting and thats why all values are getting printed on the same line

Comment: I know. The output, I wrote in the comment section, couldnt be posted with line breakers. I left it there just for u to see the output is different to the desired one.